# Different naming rules for structs and classes with ReSharper for C++

Tags: c++, resharper

Since some days I am using the new Version 2017.2 of the ReSharper Ultimate for C++ in my C++ Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 projects.
I like to use the possibility to see the hints which occur if the naming rules are not correct.

I am now looking for the possibility to define different naming rules for structs and Classes.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment it's possible to specify different naming rules only for the name of the class or struct in question, not for its members. However, there are separate naming rules by default for public and non-public member fields, which is usually the difference between classes and structs - class fields are normally private, and struct fields might be public. If this is not enough for your use case, please describe your preferred style in more detail.

Comment: I don't ask for the members of a class or a struct. I ask for the name of the class itself. By example: class Foo {}; and struct BAR {};

Comment: Go to the "ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C++ | Naming Style" options page - the "Classes and structs" naming rule should be in the list by default. Replace it with two new distinct rules, one of which is applicable only to classes and another to structs.

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for that